# In a linked list, the last node->next isn't NULL, causing a segfault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, singly-linked-list

This function adds new elements to the linked list, segfault occurs because it tries to access a field (name) of a node that shouldn't exist. However, the first node added has ->next = NULL, so I'm not sure why it enters the while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char name[50];
    struct node *next;
} *list;

list head = NULL;   //global variable

void add (char *name) {   //push

    //check if it already exists
    list node = head;
    printf("\naddent \"%s\"\head->name (prev inserted): %s\n",name,head->name);

    printf("****while:\n");

    while(node != NULL){
        printf("node: %p\n",node);      
        printf("node->name: %s\n",node->name);
        if(strcmp(node->name,name) == 0)
            return;
        node = node->next;
    }

    list newNode = malloc(sizeof(list)); 
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

int main(){
    char name[50];
    while(/*condition*/) {
        scanf("%s", name);
        add (name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
nameOne
nameTwo
nameThree
nameFour
```

I added the `printf`s to debug, and I found out that the last node->next isn't NULL (as it should) but only for "nameFour", so a SEGFAULT occurs when trying to access node->name.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list newNode = malloc(sizeof(entity));` what's `entity`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not `add` but `insertBefore`.

Comment: Does this compile? Because `list head` is declared before `list` is defined.

Comment: @Blaze corrected

Comment: You are calling standard library functions before including the headers. For functions with a variadic argument list like `printf` this invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I made a bad minimal reproducible example, my actual code doesn't look like that and my only issue was the segfault.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
printf("\naddent \"%s\"\head->name (prev inserted): %s\n",name,head->name);
```

already invokes undefined behavior because initially `head` can be equal to `NULL`. So you may not access a data member of the structure using a null-pointer as you are doing `head->name`.

I suppose that the name `entity` used in this statement

```
list newNode = malloc(sizeof(entity));
```

is a typedef name declared like for example

```
typedef struct node entity;
```

And after you updated the code in the question then the declaration of the variable `head` shall follow the declaration of the structure

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[50];
    struct node *next;
} *list;

list head = NULL;   //global variable
```

Also in the format string of this call

```
printf("\naddent \"%s\"\head->name (prev inserted): %s\n",name,head->name);
                       ^^
```

there is an invalid escape symbol.

Here is a demonstrative program that produces the expected result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char name[50];
    struct node *next;
} *list;

list head = NULL;

typedef struct node entity;

void add( const char *name ) {   //push

    //check if it already exists
    list node = head;

    while(node != NULL){
        if(strcmp(node->name,name) == 0)
            return;
        node = node->next;
    }

    list newNode = malloc(sizeof(entity));  //create entity
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}


void output()
{
    for ( list current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" -> ", current->name );
    }
    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s[] = { "nameOne", "nameTwo", "nameThree", "nameFour" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) add( s[i] );
    
    output();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"nameFour" -> "nameThree" -> "nameTwo" -> "nameOne" -> NULL
```